# For the new Android release, display tag as "android-L"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Is it possible to show the tag for Android-L questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441728/android-l-viewanimationutils-not-found) as "android-L"? The lowercase `l` is confusing.

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure that all tags are lower case, without exception. That should help the UI confusion knowing that.

Comment: Looks like you are right. The google folks should have thought about this when they named it! ;)

Comment: It is by-desgin http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83726/158100

Answer (score 1):

As Grace Note said in [the post rene linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83724/why-are-tag-names-case-insensitive/83726#83726), tags are purposefully case-insensitive. We don't have the ability to change the display for just this tag without changing the rest of the system, and we're unlikely to do that.

I do see your confusion, but I'm afraid the one instance isn't enough to warrant changing the system that works pretty well 99% of the time.